# Write a query without group subquery?

Tags: mysql

From my understanding sub queries will be called everytime a row is looked at and in this case every row will be looked at.

How do i rewrite this query? The subquery only needs to be ran once but i cant think of how to select id when i have to remove ids that only have 1 entry in the group (i want group count>1).

The purpose is to get a list of rows that have the same size as other rows

```
select id 
from file 
where size in 
    ( 
    select size from 
        (
        select count(*) as c, size 
        from file 
        group by size 
        having c>1 and size>0
        ) as t
    )
```

Comment: Please post the create statement of table file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just a subquery instead of two:

```
select id 
from file 
where size in (
    select size 
    from file 
    group by size 
    having count(*)>1 and size>0
    )
```

but if you want to use just joins, you could use something like this:

```
select distinct file.id
from file inner join file file1 on file.size = file1.size
where file.size>0 and file.id <> file1.id
```

Comment: Works well, i didnt know about the distinct keyword. This works great

Comment: @acidzombie24 yes... i forgot the `size>0` condition, but you can add it to the where clause, the query still works... i'll edit my answer... thanks!

Comment: well you didnt really need to the answer was actually reminding me of a inner join and the fact i can use the file table twice

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the optimizer should take care of it, so you don't have to.

Let MySQL EXPLAIN the statement.

And beyond this you can store the subquery in a temporary table

UPDATE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTab
  SELECT count(*) AS c, size 
  FROM file 
  GROUP BY size 
  HAVING c>1 AND size>0;

SELECT id 
FROM file 
WHERE size IN 
    ( SELECT size FROM tmpTab )
```

Comment: Whats the syntax to create a temp table? everytime i seach i find horrible results and it appears that most(all?) of the time you actually need to write a create table and define things.... (like this shows http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm)

Comment: @acidzombie24 no its as simple as a select, have a look at my updated answer :o)

Comment: hmm, ok so i guess i write `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTab` then my select seen in my subquery then my main select. Sounds good.

Comment: ahhhh `where size in (select * from tmpTab);` is running show. hmmm, how do i write `where size in tmpTab;`. I cant figure out how to write that q/o a subquery. Here is one i tried which gave me an error near t `select id from file join tmpTab t where size in t;`. I tried t.size, now the error is near t.size. hmmm

Comment: @acidzombie24 another update in my answer - but ASFAIK MySQL-Optimizer will do this right for you with your original statement. Just try EXPLAIN <your_stmt> and you will know :o)

Comment: It takes 16seconds to execute. I think i wrote the correct index code (`create index filesize on file(size);`). It still takes 16seconds. Here is the explain. http://pastebin.com/Yr6qrYsK its too big for a comment. tmptab has a count of 2813. Files has 20800. so neither are that big.

Comment: ok, here is the explain on my original query http://pastebin.com/MkzBR2i5 also +1

Answer (score 1):

how about joining againts the subquery?

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    `FILE` a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) as c, `SIZE` 
            FROM    `file `
            WHERE   `size` > 0
            GROUP BY size 
            having  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.Size = b.Size
```

Comment: in your accepted answer, why doesn't it counts the records per size?

Comment: I accepted because he showed me the distinct keyword. The way to join is pretty good even if not exact, i added size>0 part but it seems to run as fast as yours. Also he has less rep so i figure he can use it more then you